# How to create scheduled task manually that renames a file

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

I want to manually via the control panel create a scheduled task on a Windows Server 2008R2 without PowerShell 4 installed.

This scheduled task has to rename a file. The command comes down to:

```
ren P:\inetpub\wwwroot\ourapp\_app_offline.htm app_offline.htm
```

So the only thing it does is renaming a file.

What works is creating a scheduled task that calls a file that executes that command. But we want to solve it without using an extra file. Assuming we need to call CMD, we want to solve it here:

[image: What to do]

How do I call `CMD` with this rename command as an argument?

Comment: ***[Here is how to run cmd with shell program argument](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)***

Comment: Thanks. I missed that one.

Comment: Look at my edit below.  The `/c` argument must be a prefix in the _Add arguments (optional)_ box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `CMD` in the *Program/Script* box

The *Add arguments (optional)* box would contain something like this:

```
/c REN c:\dev\Monday.txt Tuesday.txt
```

There are many variations in this ***[reference](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)***.

As an example, I created a single shot task using the following command on my PC.  It executed successfully:

[image]

Comment: So also CMD in add arguments? Or CMD as a program?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this answer is wrong. Renaming should be done without the path in the second argument: [`ren [path][filename1] [filename2]`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx). Furthermore I tried adding "CMD /c" (the quotes are added automatically) in the program/script box and including the other argument behind it and that does not work. Adding a correct argument is a quoting hell. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers - you are correct.  I edited my post with some of your observations.  And created a task to test.  Will edit my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your help it works now! :) Final command: Program: `cmd`. Command: `"/c ren P:\inetpub\wwwroot\ourapp\_app_offline.htm app_offline.htm"`.